# How to pass an array of entities from findAll() to a collection field of a form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, entity

I have a very basic form that allows me to create categories, which help to group resources. I want to extend the functionality past just creating a new one to applying a sort order to the categories as well. I'm pretty close to getting it, but I'm stuck on trying to pass the array of the Category entities to the form to allow me to display them.

I think my issue stems from not passing the right info into the form when it is created, but I can see the viewData of the categories I have that get passed to it when I inspect through xdebug.

My Controller:

```
<?php

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function resourcesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $category_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ResourceCategory');

        $form_sort = $this->createForm('resource_category_sort', $category_repository->findAll());

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle::resources.html.twig',
            array(
                'form_sort'  => $form_sort->createView()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

My Category Form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ResourceCategoryFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Category Name:'))
                ->add('order', 'hidden')
                ->add('create', 'submit');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $category = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ($category->getId() !== null) {
                $form->remove('name')
                     ->add('name', 'hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
                 array(
                     'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ResourceCategory'
                 )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'resource_category';
    }
}
```

My Collection of Categories Form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ResourceCategorySortFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('categories', 'collection', array('type' => new ResourceCategoryFormType()))
                ->add('apply', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'resource_category_sort';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an array with "categories" key :

```
<?php

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function resourcesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $category_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ResourceCategory');

        $data = array();
        $data["categories"] = $category_repository->findAll();

        $form_sort = $this->createForm('resource_category_sort', $data);

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle::resources.html.twig',
            array(
                'form_sort'  => $form_sort->createView()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this not long ago and received and error message:

`The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\ResourceCategory. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "AppBundle\Entity\ResourceCategory" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\ResourceCategory to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.`

Of course, setting the data_class on this form does not resolve the issue and I still get the same error message.

Comment: So this morning I changed some things, due to upgrading to SF2.6, namely the use of OptionsResolverInterface -> OptionsResolver, and setDefaultOptions -> configureOptions. Doing this made gave me the error in the previous comment. Not sure how to resolve that...

Comment: Do you receive this error from ResourceCategorySortFormType ? You didn't set the data class, setting $data as an array should be OK...

Comment: I've got it working, but I had to go back to the now-deprecated setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) in ResourceCategoryFormType. Setting the data class on the Sort form did nothing. I'm going to figure out how to reconcile things with the deprecated issue in 2.6 and I'll report back here when done.